# How moveit connects to real hardware?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am created dynamixel hardware controller and moveit config package for my 6DOF arm.And I can able to launch demo.lauch successfully. My doubt is how can I connect it to real hardware and move my hardware from moveit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87481/how--moveit-connects-to-real-hardware?/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-10-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see
http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Executing_Trajectories_with_MoveIt

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2